# How to deploy Single SPA Root Application on AWS server?

Tags: single-spa, single-spa-angular, single-spa-react

We splitted our web application using micro frontends (Single SPA).

Root  (Configured All Sub applications)
SubApplcation1
SubApplcation2
SubApplcation3
SubApplcation4

All Sub applications are Angular project , we deployed and its running.

But Root application is not loading after deployment.

sh 'npm install @angular/cli@14.0.0'

sh 'npm i -D typescript@4.6.4'

sh 'npm install -g create-single-spa'

sh 'npm i single-spa-angular'

sh 'npm run build:webpack'

dir("dist")

{

sh 'jar cvf Root.war .'

}

Root application not loading after deployment.